# Unity runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 96 (main.mm:96) causing crash on mostly iPads

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am getting at the below crash error on Crashlytics. I couldn't find any solution about that and I didn't understand the reason. 95% happening on iPads.

I implemented at this link advise but didn't work for me

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/610#issuecomment-618897361

Thanks in advance for your helps.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2d318 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fc24 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fbbc abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 30
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d0b4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 116
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2d040 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5acc weak_register_no_lock + 392
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0xb440 objc_initWeak + 400
7  UIKitCore                      0x1d70c4 -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 1980
8  UIKitCore                      0x2b6fb4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1516
9  UIKitCore                      0x1dd664 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 140
10 CoreAutoLayout                 0x85c4 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 88
11 UIKitCore                      0x26cd78 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 840
12 UIKitCore                      0x19dbd8 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 168
13 UIKitCore                      0x1afa5c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 400
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x11f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x11b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
18 CoreFoundation                 0x51800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
19 CoreFoundation                 0xb704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
21 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
22 UIKitCore                      0x514648 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
23 UIKitCore                      0x295d90 UIApplicationMain + 364
24 UnityFramework                 0x1a398 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 96 (main.mm:96)
25 LaserSplit                     0x7d58 main + 28 (main.mm:28)
26 ???                            0x10076dce4 (Missing)
```

Comment: Lasersplit sounds odd. Is that something you made?

Comment: Yes it’s name of the game

Comment: Sadly only you know what your code does somewhere there is an unhandled exception